# Can anyone tell me why I am getting all zeros in my date field

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm fairly new to php, yes I know about the SQL injection attack, just trying to make this work.  Everything posts to the mysql table properly except the date, I keep getting all zeros.  Why?  The field is set to datetime.

```
include('../htconfig/dbConfig.php'); 
$dbSuccess = false;
$dbConnected = mysql_connect($db['hostname'],$db['username'],$db['password']);

if ($dbConnected) {     
    $dbSelected = mysql_select_db($db['database'],$dbConnected);
    if ($dbSelected) {
        $dbSuccess = true;
    }   
}
$Sldate = date("m-d-Y");
$data_back = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));


    $userName = $data_back->{"User"};
    $password = $data_back->{"Pword"};
    $SoldTo = $data_back->{"Soldto"};
    $SoldPrice = $data_back->{"SoldPrice"};
    $SoldEmail= $data_back->{"Email"};
    $VIN = $data_back->{"VIN"};



mysql_query("UPDATE tblinventory SET SOLD ='1',DATESLD = '$Sldate', DealerName='$SoldTo', SoldPrice = '$SoldPrice', DealerEmail = '$SoldEmail' WHERE VIN =$VIN");
echo ('SOLD');

///send email

?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What is this? `$data_back->{"User"};` -- That is a very unnecessary bit of code. Try `$data_back->User`.

Comment: I know some of this code is bad, just starting in php and in all the courses I have none have anything on PDO, I am running into a few problems as I am learning.  Once I am finished the courses I will jump into PDO, just trying to get through this first.  Thanks for the tutorial though, I'll be using it very soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL expects your date to be in YYYY-MM-DD format, not MM-DD-YYYY.

```
$Sldate = date("Y-m-d");
```

You could also remove the PHP portion of this code and do this directly in your SQL

```
DATESLD = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your are getting 00-00-00 00:00:00 is because MYSQL can't recognize your datetime as valid so it inserts a default value. Sometimes you'll also get 1947-08-25 19:31:00.

Your datetime object will need to be formatted correctly. PHP's DateTime class makes easy work of this, however you need version 5.2 to use it.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$Sldate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```